# How much energy does a bird use gliding, vs how much energy is there to capture in the moving air?

Tags: energy-conservation, aerodynamics, aircraft

So I have this image in my head of a robotic pigeon with a wind turbine strapped to it.

For the purpose of this mental image, imagine the robotic pigeon is in every relevant way just like an actual pigeon; except crucially it's main energy source is electrical, and so it runs on battery power not burning carbohydrates.

I figure that it takes quite a bit of energy for the pigeon to take off, and generally beat it's wings. But what about when it is cruising / gliding at high altitudes? I'd seen someone likening a bird gliding to energetically equivalent to rolling down-hill on a bicycle.

So now I'm thinking about strapping a wind turbine to the pigeon. Nothing is stopping me from doing that part; but would it be worth it? What size turbine would I need to recover a reasonable amount of energy at those higher altitudes, would it be too large for the pigeon to take off in the first place? I'm imagining that there would be some sort of shutter system to eliminate most of the turbine drag during take off. The mechanism only engages at high altitude, such that during take off it is only adding extra weight and marginal drag (relative to the full drag of it in operation).

In my mental image the pigeon would compensate it's flight to account of the weight + drag of the turbine. I'm imaging it having a sort of sinusodal dip-and-rise style flight pattern, in which when the turbine is engaged it would do a dive, picking up speed, charging the batteries, then use the momentum and energy gained from the charge to climb a bit (maybe getting back to original altitude, probably not though) and repeating.

In the above instance, would the turbine add anything to the pigeons flight distance, all other things being equal?

---

#### Edit

Considering the example of a propeller powered plane with a turbine strapped to it made me realise that I really just want to ask about the relative efficiency of generating thrust with propeller / turbine vs beating of a feathered wing.

So I think my real question is: Can I generate enough thrust/airspeed from beating two feathered wings to power a wind turbine and still have energy left over for forward motion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Birds ride thermals and extract energy from the atmosphere by doing so. See here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal

So it's not just rolling down-hill, it's like rolling downhill but the hill is moving up, like a treadmill that is taking you where you want to go.

A machine will be more efficient than a biological wing, but using a wing to power a turbine to power a machine will be less efficient. Every step loses power to heat. There's no free energy. Birds have an easy time gliding because the extra energy comes from the atmosphere.

Hang gliders and hot air balloons ride the wind, as well.

Comment: So my robot pigeon could navigate to a thermal column under it's own power, then deploy a turbine to recharge; rinse and repeat?
Assuming losses from heat, would that be any better than not having the turbine in the first place?

Comment: The idea of the turbine is to store some energy to recharge, but the way birds store energy is in the form of gaining height in the air as potential energy, as thermals lift them upwards. Which is a form of energy storage which doesn't add battery and turbine weight! If your robot bird is not altitude limited, why not just use the height to store energy? So I have to say, it's probably better not to have the turbine in the first place. Since you can store energy as height.